# Python: Handle Exceptions in Background Process

Tags: python, selenium, exception

We are using selenium in background processes, and I wonder what is the correct way to handle and debug exceptions that occurs from a browser. Ideally, I would want to have the name of the exception, the traceback, the browser source code and a screenshot.

Something like that :

```
def main():
    try:
         work_to_do.do_selenium_stuff()
    except:
         to_log = {}
         to_log['traceback'] = traceback.format_exc()
         to_log['source_code'] = browser.page_source()
         to_log['screenshot'] = browser.take_screenshot()
```

We have a lot of processes in the background, it can be great to store everything in a database for future relevant grep. For now, we are handling everything by hand, I feel that's stupid.